# Quiero un método para obtener tres rangos de fechas distintas desde una DB y almacenarlos en un arreglo

Tags: c#, mysql, array, base-de-datos, .net

Este es mi codigo en el cual tengo registrado 3 rangos de fechas distintas y estoy mostrando en los Labels. y me funciona todo bien hasta ahi
Lo que quiero hacer almacenar en un arreglo esos 3 rangos de fechas para luego mostrar y colorear en un MonthCalendar 
Alguna Idea? por favor.

```cs
DataTable dt = ConexionDB.GetDataTable(sql);

                fecha_i.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                fecha_f.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();

                fecha_i2.Text = dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                fecha_f2.Text = dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[2].ToString();

                fecha_i3.Text = dt.Rows[2].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                fecha_f3.Text = dt.Rows[2].ItemArray[2].ToString();
```

Comment: Dada la respuesta que te dieron a tu anterior pregunta, cual es exactamente el problema con esta? porque ahi esta lo que estas pidiendo en esta pregunta...

Comment: @gbianchi quiero mostrar esos tres rangos de fechas en un MonthCalendar